# Getting a Model dynamic by knowing its name

Tags: django, django-models

I use Django 2.1.

I have a general utility/function(using celery) that I call from the `save` method of a Model(is an abstract Model, inherited by other Models).

Because the data from the function will be serialize, I pass to it the Model name and PK.

```
class A(models.Model)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     send_async(model_name=type(self).__name__, pk=self.id))




class B(A)
class C(A)
```

Later, I want to query the Model, but I don't know how to get the Model:

I tried:

```
 model = apps.get_model('django_app_name.{}'.format(model_name))
```

I get the following error:

```
No installed app with label 'django_app_name'.
```

Also:

```
 model = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_name)
```

This doesn't trow an error, but very strange behavior 'recalls' the View with different arguments, and off course no results.

Comment: What does `type(self).__name__` prints out?

Comment: the class name, in the example B or  C(which inherits A)

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the app which has the model, not `django_app_name`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the model name, try this:

```
send_async(model_name=self.__class__.__name__, pk=self.id)
```

`instance.__class__.__name__` will return the class name

Answer (score 0):

You should do like so:

```
class A(models.Model)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       send_async(
            model_name=self._meta.model_name,
            app_label=self._meta.app_label,
            pk=self.id
       )
```

And in send_async:

```
def send_async(model_name, app_label, pk):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model_name)
    instance = content_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=pk)
    ...
```

For more information about it see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/